# Combine results within a monad without do

Tags: haskell

I have a snippet of code which can abstractly be described as this:

```
foobar = do
  foo <- getFoo
  bar <- getBar
  return $ foo ++ bar
```

It feels like there must be a nice way to combine `foo` and `bar` that doesn't require four lines of `do` notation - some infix operator I can apply directly to `getFoo` and `getBar` maybe (perhaps specifying `(++)` as a combining function, but given that the results are a `Monoid` I shouldn't really have to...) - but I can't find anything like this.

I searched Hoogle for things like `Monad m => (a -> a -> a) -> m a -> m a -> m a` and `Monad m, Monoid a => m a -> m a -> m a` but came up empty.

Is there a combine function/operator like this?

Comment: "I searched Hoogle for things like `Monad m => (a -> a -> a) -> m a -> m a -> m a`"... literally the first result for this search is a correct answer, `liftM2`. Four out of the first five would work, and eight out of the first ten. (You could perhaps quibble about `liftU2`, but even striking that it's 3/5 and 7/10.)

Comment: I wonder if I had some other filter active, then, because my searches for that literally came up with 0 results. Now (on a different computer) it doesn't, so that's nice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Applicative notation is rather popular:

```
foobar = (++) <$> getFoo <*> getBar
```

This naturally extends to n-ary functions. The expression `f <$> action1 <*> ... <*> actionN` works under the following hypotheses:

```
-- F is any applicative (including monads)
actioni :: F ti   -- for i in 1..N
f :: t1 -> t2 -> ... -> tN -> r
```

in which case

```
f <$> action1 <*> ... <*> actionN :: F r
```

Comment: Thanks - Applicative was exactly the abstraction I didn't realize I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

The function you were searching for is called [`liftA2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:liftA2).

Use it like this:

```
foobar = liftA2 (++) getFoo getBar
```